# R - search for numerical sequences

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence

I have a data frame looking like this:

```
   nr  grp start stop l1 ratio
   11   1   300  350  +   1.0                  
   12   1   400  450  -   0.8                  
   13   1    50  550  +   1.0                  
   14   1   600  650  -   1.0                  
   21   1   800  850  -   1.0                  
   36   1  1000 1050  +   0.0       
   37   1  1100 1200  +   0.9
   38   1  1250 1300  -   0.7
   39   1  1350 1400  +   1.0
```

and I have to find sequences of consecutive numbers and move it to a new df.
I need to pull out the whole first row of the sequence and replace only the value for the stop column taken from the last row of the sequence.

The final df should look like this:

```
  nr  grp start stop l1 ratio
  11   1   300  650   +   1.0                  
  36   1   1000 1400  -   0.8
```

I tried to do it this way:

```
t1<- read.table('aa.txt',sep = "\t", header=TRUE)
head(t1)
t1$chk <- NA
dl <- length(t1$nr)
for (i in 1:dl){
  if(isTRUE(t1$nr[i]+1 == t1$nr[i+1])){
  t1$chk[i] <- "t"  
  }else{
    t1$chk[i] <- 'F'
    }
}
```

and I receive this:

```
   nr  grp start stop l1 ratio chk
   11   1   300  350  +   1.0   t             
   12   1   400  450  -   0.8   t              
   13   1    50  550  +   1.0   t              
   14   1   600  650  -   1.0   F              
   21   1   800  850  -   1.0   F              
   36   1  1000 1050  +   0.0   t   
   37   1  1100 1200  +   0.9   t
   38   1  1250 1300  -   0.7   t
   39   1  1350 1400  +   1.0   F
```

After that, I wanted to move all rows which in the chk column have "t" to a new df. Unfortunately, I have a problem because the last number of sequences is not included in it. Does anyone have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: Which sequence you are expecting and not present?

Comment: Why row with `nr = 21` is not there in your final output?

Comment: Because a single reading is not treated as a sequence.

Comment: How the values of the `l1` and `ratio` columns should be filled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy with data.table:

```
DT <- fread("   nr  grp start stop l1 ratio
            11   1   300  350  +   1.0                  
            12   1   400  450  -   0.8                  
            13   1    50  550  +   1.0                  
            14   1   600  650  -   1.0                  
            21   1   800  850  -   1.0                  
            36   1  1000 1050  +   0.0       
            37   1  1100 1200  +   0.9
            38   1  1250 1300  -   0.7
            39   1  1350 1400  +   1.0")

setDT(DT) #if you haven't imported with fread

#create group ID, here for didactic reason
DT[, groups := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(nr) != 1))]

#take first row and replace stop from last row
DT[, if (.N > 1) {
  res <- .SD[1]
  res$stop <- .SD[.N, stop]
  res
  } else NULL, by = groups]
#   groups nr grp start stop l1 ratio
#1:      1 11   1   300  650  +     1
#2:      3 36   1  1000 1400  +     0
```

Answer (score 2):

We can create groups for every change in sequence using `diff` and select only first row from each group if there are more than 1 row in the group and update the value of `stop` to last value in the group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
   group_by(group = cumsum(c(1, diff(nr) != 1))) %>%
   mutate(stop = last(stop)) %>%
   filter(n() > 1 & row_number() == 1) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   select(-group)

#     nr   grp start  stop l1    ratio
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <fct> <dbl>
#1    11     1   300   650 +         1
#2    36     1  1000  1400 +         0
```

Comment: Seems to me that the `stop` column must contain the last value in the sequence. Honestly, I have no idea about what `l1` and `ratio` should contain.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention this l1 and the ratio have the value of the first line of the sequence

Comment: @Ronak Shah Thank you very much. And you still have an idea how to pull the stop value from the last line of the sequence and insert it into the first line of the sequence.

Comment: @Kepasere Updated the answer with that should work now.

Comment: @nicola Thanks. I initially thought they just want to subset the first row.